# Exploring the Power and Purpose of Routes_API in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been delving into the intricacies of utilizing `Routes_API` within `Next.js`, and my research has led me to ponder when and why it's appropriate to use this feature. From what I've gathered, `Routes_API` in `Next.js` becomes particularly valuable when you're in the process of constructing a fullstack application. In this scenario, `Routes_API` essentially serves as the gateway to your backend APIs within your `Next.js` application.

However, a question has arisen: What if there are already established APIs provided by the backend team that I need to integrate with? In such cases, does it remain necessary to implement `Routes_API`? I would greatly appreciate comprehensive responses to help me gain a deeper understanding of this matter. Your insights will be immensely valuable. Thank you!